# Scrabble word finder

Tags: python, performance, generator

I have been working on a Scrabble Word Finder for a couple of days now and have it working pretty much but would love to improve the efficiency.

The code is made up of 2 classes: one for creating and managing a pool of letter tiles and another for iterating over a word dictionary (from a .txt file) to check/score word matches in the letter rack (from the tile pool) and a cross letter. As I mentioned, everything works so far, but I feel like it could be faster. I have tried taking advantage of generators but am running into problems with them in the `WordFinder` class as I am not very experienced in them. I will post my code as well as the code I am using to test it.

**scrabble_challenge.py (My Code)**

```
import csv
import random


class TilePool(list):
    def __init__(self):
        """
        Initializes the Tile Pool by reading the given 'tile.csv' file and converting it into a tile pool list with one
        list item per tile based on the amount of tiles for each letter

        """

        # Open csv file
        with open("tiles.csv") as f:
            # Read csv into list of lists of each lines values
            tiles_csv = csv.reader(f, delimiter=",")

            # Convert the list into a tile pool
            list.__init__(self, ((line[0], line[1])
                                 for line in tiles_csv if len(line[0]) == 1
                                 for x in xrange(int(line[2]))))

            del tiles_csv

    def pop(self, tile_count=None):
        """
        Returns a list of tiles from the tile pool based on the amount specified in the 'tile_count' parameter and the
        amount of tiles left in the pool.

        :param tile_count: The amount of tiles desired (If not specified up to 7 tiles will be returned)
        :return: A new list of tiles from tile pool
        """
        assert len(self), "# Tile Pool is empty"

        # When the tile count is None return (up to) 7 tiles
        if tile_count is None:
            tile_count = 7

        assert tile_count in xrange(1, 8), "# Tile Count must be between 1 and 7"

        new_tiles = []
        counter = 1
        while len(self) and counter <= tile_count:  # Return tiles while tile pool has tiles AND tile count not reached
            rand_choice = random.choice(self)  # Get a random tile
            new_tiles.append(rand_choice)  # Add it to new_tiles list
            self.remove(rand_choice)  # Delete it from pool

            counter += 1

        return new_tiles

    def view_pool(self):
        """
        Prints each tile in the pool with it's 'Score' value
        :return: None
        """
        assert len(self), "# Tile Pool is empty"

        for tile in self:
            print("{letter}: {score}".format(letter=tile[0], score=tile[1]))


class WordFinder:
    def list_words(self, letters, cross_letter):
        if cross_letter is None:
                cross_letter = ''

        with open("word_dictionary.txt") as x:
            word_dict = (line.strip() for line in x)

            accepted = []
            for word in word_dict:
                if cross_letter in word:
                    min_cross = list(word.replace(cross_letter, '', 1))

                    score = 0
                    for letter in letters:
                        if not min_cross:
                            accepted.append((word, score))
                            break

                        elif letter[0] in min_cross:
                            min_cross.remove(letter[0])
                            score += int(letter[1])

            return accepted
```

**testing_code.py**

```
import sys
import scrabble_challenge


def main():
    cross_letters = [chr(x) for x in xrange(97, 123)]
    cross_letters.insert(0, None) # the first word has no cross letter
    tile_pool = scrabble_challenge.TilePool()
    word_finder = scrabble_challenge.WordFinder()
    while len(tile_pool):
        letters = tile_pool.pop()
        for cross_letter in cross_letters:
            for word, score in word_finder.list_words(letters, cross_letter):
                print word, score
    return 0

if __name__=='__main__':
    sys.exit(main())
```

---

I would like to have some way of initializing the `word_dict` generator in the `__init__` so it isn't being generated in every loop in my **testing_code.py**. But when I tried adding this:

```
with open("word_dictionary.txt") as x:
    word_dict = (line.strip() for line in x)
```

in the `__init__` I would get a "ValueError: I/O operation on closed file" error. But this structure works on the list comprehension in `class TilePool`.

I'd also like to get the `list_words` method to `yield` as opposed to `return`. My attempts at both of these have failed. Any other code efficiency suggestions (for **scrabble_challenge.py**) are certainly welcome.

Comment: `(line.strip() for line in x)` is a generator expression - that means it's evaluated lazily (on demand). You could probably replace it with a list comprehension `[line.strip() for line in x]` which is evaluated immediately to the full word list. That would probably fix your read-the-file-every-time issue.

Comment: Well the only reason i decided to use a generator for that is because the dictionary.txt has like 80,000 words in it. The problem I am having with it is that if leave it in the `list_words` method it generates it multiple times in the test code and If i put it in the __init__ it throws an error.

Comment: Another performance improvement might be to order words by score, (and then by letter count as a secondary sort maybe). You would then be able to search for the first matching word and know that must be the highest scoring, without needing to check the low scoring words like 'it', 'to' etc.

Comment: But your issue is that using the generator outside the `with file():` context results in the closed file error. You create the wordfinder once, so put the loading of the words into that class's init as self.words.

Comment: A further optimisation might be to pre-compute every words letter-frequency (maybe using a `Counter`?) and then do the same with the current `letters`. That should get rid of the need to keep removing letters from strings, which might speed things up.

Comment: You should try profiling before trying to optimize - time some of your loops and see which ones take the longest. Focus on those. I'll try to take a look from my pc when I get home.

Comment: See [_How can you profile a Python script?_](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/582336/how-can-you-profile-a-python-script)

Comment: Please add your `tiles.csv` file to your question or upload it [somewhere](http://pastebin.com) and add a link to it in your question if it's huge.

Comment: @thomasd Sorry i did not know of that site or i would have put it up there.

Comment: @martineau Sorry i did not know of that site or i would have put it up there.

Comment: @TomDalton Ok cool. This will give me a bunch of avenues to explore. Thanks a bunch.

Comment: @UNOwen That makes sense. I didn't know you could do that. Thanks for the advice and link.